# JPA and Hibernate Cascade DELETE OneToMany does not work

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, cascade

I've been reading post after post and article after article trying to get cascade deletes to work with JPA/Hibernate in the latest Spring Boot version. I've read that You have to use Hibernate specific cascades and I've read that you don't. I've read that they just don't work but it seems to be a mixed bag. Everything I've tried doesn't work. The relationship is bi-directional.

Doesn't Work:

```
@Entity
public class Brand {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.DELETE})
    @JsonManagedReference("brand-tax-rate")
    private List<TaxRate> taxRates;

}
```

Doesn't Work:

```
@Entity
public class Brand {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference("brand-tax-rate")
    private List<TaxRate> taxRates;

}
```

Does anything work other than deleting the `TaxRates` prior to deleting the `Brand` ?

My test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, SpringSecurityConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional
public class CascadeTests {

    @Autowired
    private BrandService brandService;

    @Autowired
    private TaxRateLoaderService taxRateLoaderService;

    @Autowired
    private TaxRateService taxRateService;

    @Autowired
    private TaxRateRepository taxRateRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BrandRepository brandRepository;

    @Test
    public void testCascadeWorks() throws Exception {

        taxRateLoaderService.loadData(null, 10);

        // if I uncomment this then I'm good
        // but shouldn't have to if cascade works
        //taxRateService.deleteAll();
        brandService.deleteAll();

        List<TaxRate> rates = Lists.newArrayList(taxRateRepository.findAll());
        List<Brand> brands = Lists.newArrayList(brandRepository.findAll());

        Assert.assertEquals(rates.size(), 0);
        Assert.assertEquals(brands.size(), 0);
    }
}
```

Error for reference:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity
>   constraint violation: "FKC4BCIKI2WSPO6WVGPO3XLA2Y9: PUBLIC.TAX_RATE
>   FOREIGN KEY(BRAND_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.BRAND(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
>   delete from brand where id=? [23503-192]

UPDATE: modified my `brandService.deleteAll()` method to do the following:

```
@Override
public void deleteAll() {
    Iterable<Brand> iter = this.brandRepository.findAll();
    iter.forEach(brand -> this.brandRepository.delete(brand) );
}
```

Still does not work.

UPDATE 2: It only appears to be a problem via tests. Cascade seems to work okay with the app running.

Comment: What does brandService.deleteAll() look like? Can you add the code?

Comment: `brandRepository.deleteAll()` is all it is doing. My Repositories are all CrudRepository interfaces.

Comment: What is the result. An exception? If so turn on SQL logging to see what is happening.

Comment: JPA doesn't have cascade = CascadeType.DELETE. I assume this is a typo? The standard JPA annotation should work so you would need to post the exception if any.

Comment: modified typo and added stacktrace. I understand it should work, I'm saying it doesn't.

Comment: There's no SQL being generated in the log for deleting the TaxRates.

Comment: Post your whole test class .

Comment: I've edited the question to include the test.

Comment: JPA does not specify a `deleteAll()` method. This is a Sping Data convenience method. Looking at the Code it does a findAll() and then delete for each found item so should work.  What happens if you simply call delete(anInstance)? Does this cascade correctly. You are definitely calling `repository.deleteAll()` and not`deleteAllInBatch()` as I can see how that would break the cascading.

Comment: Updated question to reflect that change, still no go.

Comment: Hi Gregg. Still having issues? I have actually been using this functionality in Spring Data for the last few days without any issues.

Comment: I am, but only in tests. As I said in my latest update, it works fine running the app, but it doesn't cascade in my tests. Are they working in your tests? If so, I'd love to see an example of one of your tests. Maybe I'm not initiating things correctly for it to work? Too much unit and not enough integration?

Answer (score 13):

I think you want to take a look at [`@OnDelete`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-ondelete) annotation which generates a DDL-level cascade delete.

This will add an `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the `FOREIGN KEY` definition if you're using the automatic schema generation (e.g. hbm2ddl). However, using [Flyway is almost always a better choice](https://flywaydb.org/) than hbm2ddl.

Your mapping becomes:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonManagedReference("brand-tax-rate")
private List<TaxRate> taxRates;
```

Comment: Just a note to readers. If I understand this well this will add ON DELETE CASCADE to the foreign key in the SQL table if you use Hibernate to generate the schema.

Comment: That's right. The OP wants to clear out the DB schema between tests. Check out this [blog post](http://www.greggbolinger.com/truncate-all-tables-in-spring-boot-jpa-app/).

Comment: But answers are not only for the person asking. We should try to explain the answer for anyone who gets here.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot as soon as I have a chance.

Comment: This works for Hibernate, but is it possible to do for general JPA?